# Default arguments in a function when using decorators

Tags: python, decorator, default-value

I cannot really tell how to use *args and **kwargs when combined with decorators and default arguments. Let me give you a MWE.

```
def outer(f):
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        print("args:", args)
        print("kwargs:", kwargs)

    return inner

@outer
def simple(x, y):
    pass
```

Running the `simple` function passing arguments in a different format. So:

Running:

```
simple(10, 20)

args: (10, 20)
kwargs: {}
```

Running:

```
simple(x=10, y=20)

args: ()
kwargs: {'x': 10, 'y': 20}
```

Running:

```
simple(10, y=20)

args: (10,)
kwargs: {'y': 20}
```

All of these seem to be expected. What I cannot understand is if I define the `simple` function with a default value something like:

```
@outer
def simple(x, y=100):
    pass
```

If I then run `simple(10)` I would have expected the outcome to be:

```
args: (10,)
kwargs: {'y': 100}
```

but I get

```
args: (10,)
kwargs: {}
```

instead. Probably my understanding is not that good, so how could I achieve the expected result?

Comment: You never actually use `f`. Even if you were, you're printing in the decorator, which doesn't alone have any relation to the function it's wrapping. You could inspect the passed function to extract its defaults, but that'd be messy. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Default argument values aren't passed like normal arguments. They are part of the definition of the function itself, and assigned to the corresponding parameter *after* passed arguments have been accounted for, if the parameter remains unset.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Thanks, what I want to do is more complex and it doesn't have to do with just outputing the *args and **kwargs from a function. I just provided a MWE, which is the critical bit for me to solve.

Comment: @chepner Thanks, that was the piece of information I was missing! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case `**kwargs` is not about the function signature, it's about how you called it.
And your call

```py
simple(10)
```

have only specified one positional argument.

Decorator (wrapper) knows nothing about the function and its default arguments.
It just passes the arguments it received further.

```py
simple(*(10,), **{})
```

If you want to do some excercise and write decorator that is informed about the defaults of a function it is wrapping, I suggest to take a look at [`inspect.signature()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#introspecting-callables-with-the-signature-object).

Comment: Thanks, I will try that and see what the effect is.

Answer (score 1):

Facing the same issue and following @madbird answer, here's a snippet of a decorator that is aware of the `kwargs` defaults for the function it wraps:

```
def outer(f):

    signature = inspect.signature(f)

    default_kwargs = {
        kw: value.default for kw, value in signature.parameters.items() if value.default != inspect.Signature.empty
    }

    @wraps(f)
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        print("args:", args)
        print("kwargs:", default_kwargs | kwargs)

    return inner
```

It inspects the signature of the func it wraps, extracts all parameters with a default value (those whose default isn't a `Signature.empty`) to a dict and then applies it with the provided `kwargs` of the wrapped function in-order.

(Tested in Python 3.9)